# Intuitive explanation behind perpendicular bisector formula using complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider, the equation

$ |z+i|  = |z-i|$

Now the interpretation of this equation is that it is the locus of points which are the perpendicular bisector of the line connecting $i$ and $-i$. But how would we justify this reason/ motivate it?

Comment: Should that first "1" be an "i", perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean $i$ and $-1$?

Comment: $|z+1|$ is the distance of $z$ from $-1$, and $|z-i|$ is the distance of $z$ from $i$. So this describes the points having same distance from $-1$ and $i$.

Comment: oh yeah @paul nice catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z-a|=|z-b|$ then the distance from $z$ to $a$ is equal to the distance from $z$ to $b$. Therefore the triangle with vertices $z,a,b$ is isosceles, so the line from $z$ to the mid-point between $a$ and $b$ is perpendicular to the line from $a$ to $b$. Conversely, any point on that line is equidistant from $a$ and $b$.

Comment: now what if its like $ |z-a| = |z+b|$ , the concept of distance is longer there

Comment: $|z + b| = |z - (-b)|$

Answer (score 0):

In general, $|z-a|=|z-b|$ iff $z$ is on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment with endpoints $a,\,b$. To see this, note first that $|z-w|$ is a translationally and rotationally invariant distance in the complex plane, and the resulting distances' ratios are also invariant under scaling. So without loss of generality, assume $a=-1,\,b=1,\,z=x+iy,\,x,\,y\in\Bbb R$ , whence$$|z-a|^2=(x+1)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+1+2x,$$and similarly $|z-b^2|=x^2+y^2+1-2x$. These are equal iff $x=0$, i.e. $z$ is on the bisector.

Comment: what do you mean by
1. translational invariance
2. rotational invariance

Comment: @DDD4C4U If you drag the plane, or rotate it around a point, distances don't change.